# Disable auto-suggestions in EditText using PasswordTransformationMethod

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, passwords

I want to programmatically disable the auto-completion for my EditText (**not in XML**).

This EditText is in an alert dialog which i included in my Fragment (without creating an xml layout):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LinearLayout linlay= new LinearLayout(getActivity());
linlay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
final EditText passEditText = new EditText(getActivity());
linlay.addView(passEditText);

passEditText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

I know i can create an xml layout and use `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions`.

Is there a way to do it programmatically in the Fragment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
passEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```

or

```
passEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)
```

See [setRawInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType%28int%29)

Comment: This does not work for EditText (on Samsung s3). The suggestions are removed, but the characters can be seen in the EditText now, no * representation.